# Современные форматы изображения JPEG 2000, JPEG XR и WebP

Tags: php, веб-программирование, webp

прошу помощи решить проблему при оптимизации сайта ,  гугл pagespeed просит "Используйте современные форматы изображений" (JPEG 2000, JPEG XR и WebP) 
попробовал формат

**WebP** - вроде работает но оказалось он не отображает в Firefox , Safari

**JPEG 2000** - вообще не могу вывести на Web как обычную картинку

подскажите может кто-то сталкивался с такими форматами как с ними правильно работать или как вывести на web JPEG 2000 , работает он вообще в других браузерах ?

Comment: просто, используй большую степень сжатия на 10-20%

Comment: картинки вроде сжал , хочу поднять показатели по pagespeed  но он просит современные форматы , получается он меня заставляет выводить частично не работающие картинки

Comment: мало ли что он просит, головой надо тоже думать, найди для себя баланс - либо высший балл гугля, либо комфорт для юзеров.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Можно использовать тег picture:

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="path/to/image.webp">
    <source type="image/jp2" srcset="path/to/image.jp2">
    <source type="image/jxr" srcset="path/to/image.jxr">
    <img src="path/to/image.jpg">
</picture>
```

**UPD от 26.01.2019:** пример реалиализации отдачи `webp` на стороне веб-сервера, например `Nginx`.

Как правило браузер передаёт серверу информацию о поддерживаемых технологий. Например Chrome передаёт такие значения `Accept: image/webp, */*;q=0.8`. Поэтому можно отдавать определённые изображения на стороне сервера.

Пример Nginx:

```
location / {

  # проверка заголовка Accept и наличия версии файла в .webp 
  if ($http_accept ~* "webp")    { set $webp_accept "true"; }
  if (-f $request_filename.webp) { set $webp_local  "true"; }

  # если WebP есть, то передать Vary
  if ($webp_local = "true") {
    add_header Vary Accept;
  }

  # если клиент поддерживает WebP, то передать файл
  if ($webp_accept = "true") {
    rewrite (.*) $1.webp break;
  }
}
```

Пример Apache:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.webp -f
  RewriteRule (.+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [T=image/webp,E=accept:1]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
</IfModule>

AddType image/webp .webp
```

Примеры для разных веб-серверов можно найти [здесь](https://github.com/igrigorik/webp-detect/).

Comment: спасибо за совет учту этот момент

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесник дополнил ответ, может быть будет полезным.