# Изображения не нравятся google speed

Tags: оптимизация-сайтов

На сайте есть различные изображения форматов (`png` и `jpg`). Оптимизирую их без потери качества программками `opipng` и `jpegoptim`. Раньше google всё нравилось, а теперь вредничает и говорит ещё можно ***сжать и использовать современный тип изображения***. Команды оптимизации `png`:

```
optipng -o 7 *.png
```

Оптимизация jpg:

```
jpegoptim *.jpg
```

Что я делаю не так, или что я не доделал)?

Comment: Не пробовали воспользоваться другими инструментами для сжатия без потери качества?

Comment: А примерно какого разрешения и размера ваши жпеги?

Comment: Тут уже обсуждалось https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915267/Современные-форматы-изображения-jpeg-2000-jpeg-xr-и-webp/915298#915298

Answer (score 1):

Либо настойчиво намекает на WebP, либо считает, что указываете браузеру при показе масштабировать до сильно не их родного разрешения.