# Как отдавать веб-сервером картинку .webp?

Tags: nginx, изображения, веб-сервер, apache2

Для оптимизации сайта использовал хранение изображений в дополнительном формате `.webp`. Суть такая: пользователь запрашивает картинку `image.jpg` ( в браузер ), веб-сервер смотрит, если есть такая-же картинка в формате `.webp` и браузер поддерживает, то отдает её. Использовал решение на `.htaccess`:

https://github.com/vincentorback/WebP-images-with-htaccess

И все прекрасно работает, но на локальном, там у меня только `Apache` ( xampp ), а вот с продакшн-сервером проблемка, на выделенном сервере стоит связка `Apache` и `nGinx`, решение через `.htaccess` не работает, я в серверах не сильно разбираюсь, но так понимаю, что статику сайта отдает именно `nGinx`, и отсюда вопрос:
Как настроить `nGinx` так, чтобы работала подмена картинки на `.webp` как я писал выше?

Comment: Узнайте можно ли править конфиги Nginx и соответственно нужным образом их настроить.

Comment: Также можете обратить внимание на мой ответ, который давал ранее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/915298/237223

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, но вот в этой [статье](https://centminmod.com/webp/) предлагают создать `webp.conf` добавляем переменную `http_accept` с параметром `webp_extension`

```
map $http_accept $webp_extension {
    default "";
    "~*webp" ".webp";
}
```

и правило

```
location ~* ^/webp/.+\.(png|jpe?g)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Vary "Accept-Encoding";
    add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    try_files $uri$webp_extension $uri =404;
  }
```