# nginx + wordpress + .webp

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, apache2

Доброго времени суток.

Есть необходимость реализовать фичу, чтобы сервер вместо .jpg/png отдавал .webp, если браузер указал его поддержку в заголовках. Вместо image.png отдавать image.webp

Запросы обрабатывает связка nginx + apache. Но, насколько я понимаю, настройку статики нужно делать через nginx.

Руководствуясь [вот этим](https://centminmod.com/webp/) и [этим](https://matteth.wordpress.com/2014/09/29/serving-webp-images-in-wordpress-with-nginx/) мануалом в файле `/etc/nginx/conf.d/webp.conf` добавил этот код

```
map $http_accept $webp_extension {
    default "";
    "~*webp" ".webp";
}
```

А в файл `/etc/nginx/conf.d/vhosts/mysite.ssl.com.conf` непосредственно в секцию server вот такой

```
location ~* ^/wp-content/.+\.(png|jpg)$ {
    add_header Vary Accept;
    try_files $uri$webp_extension $uri =404;
}
```

Изображения в uploads в форматах image.webp & image.png.webp

В mime.types формат webp прописан.

Итог: не работает. Не могу понять почему.

Comment: [Вот это решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915267/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-jpeg-2000-jpeg-xr-%d0%b8-webp/915298#915298) не помогло (

Comment: Не надо вестись на гуглоересь. Но если религия не позволят отклониться от курса ~партии~ гуглоразводил, то вот https://wordpress.org/plugins/webp-express/ напр

Comment: Нужно именно через nginx. Всякие стильномодномолодежные плагины просьба не предлагать. Перепробовал штук 5 подобных плагинов (этот был в их числе). Не подходят по разным причинам.

upd: а чем гуглоразводилы-то не угодили? webp весит на порядок меньше, чем эти ваши жипеги.

Comment: Если "именно через nginx", тогда метка `wordpress` тут лишняя.

Answer (score 0):

Вот работающий код для использования webp. Секция server:

```
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name site.ru;
        rewrite ^(.*) https://site.ru$1 permanent;
}
server {
        listen     443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/site.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/site.key;        

        server_name site.ru;

        root /var/www/site;
        index index.php;

        include snippets/webp.conf;
        include snippets/wp.conf;
}
```

Обработка webp сделана в сниппете, чтобы легко можно было отключить или добавить на другой сайт (snippets/webp.conf):

```
if ($http_accept ~* "webp") {
    set $webp "A";
}

if (-f $request_filename.webp) {
    set $webp "${webp}E";
}

set $webfile $uri;
if ( $webp = "AE" ) {
    set $webfile $uri.webp;
}

location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|tiff)$ {
    expires max;
    add_header Vary Accept;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";      

    try_files $webfile $uri =404;
}
```

Ну, и более или менее стандартный сниппет для WordPress (snippets/wp.conf), вы можете использовать свой:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include fastcgi_params;

    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;            

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;        
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}

location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|woff2|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|htm|html)$ {
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31600000, public";
}
```

В синппете webp.conf проверяется, что браузер поддерживает webp (`$http_accept`). Затем проверяется, есть ли файл вида `картинка-с-расширением.webp` (`$request_filename.webp`). Если оба условия выполнены, то отдаём браузеру файл с расширением .webp.

Код работает для файлов jpg, jpeg, pnp, tiff, который должны иметь файлы-дубликаты вида

- картинка.jpg.webp
- картинка.png.webp

и т.д.